# How to invert the pentagon created using CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I want to create pentagon which is pointing downward (reverse). But I don't how to mentions points.

```css
#pentagon {
 margin:70px 0 5px 20px;
 position: relative;
 width: 110px;
 border-width: 100px 36px 0;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #abefcd transparent;
}
#pentagon:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 top: -170px;
 left: -36px;
 border-width: 0 90px 70px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: transparent transparent #abefcd;
}
```

```html
<div id="pentagon"></div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR:** (Solution)

The simplest way to invert that pentagon would be to invert the borders that are used in creating it like in the below snippet:

```css
#pentagon {
  margin: 0px 0 5px 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 110px;
  border-width: 0px 36px 100px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #abefcd transparent;
}
#pentagon:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  top: 100px;
  left: -36px;
  border-width: 70px 90px 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #abefcd transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="pentagon"></div>
```

---

**How is the pentagon shape in question created?**

The pentagon shape that you have shown in question is created as follows:

- The main element has a `border-top` of 100px whose color is `#abefcd`, it has `border-left` and `border-right` as 36px but they are transparent. This produces a trapezoid which is wider at the top and shorter at the bottom.
- The pseudo element has a `border-bottom` of 70px whose color is `#abefcd`, it has `border-left` and `border-right` as 90px but they are transparent. This produces a triangular shape which is then placed on top of the main element using absolute positioning.

Both these together produce the pentagon. I have changed the border colors in the below snippet so that you can see it visually.

```css
#pentagon {
 margin:70px 0 5px 20px;
 position: relative;
 width: 110px;
 border-width: 100px 36px 0;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: red transparent;
}
#pentagon:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 top: -170px;
 left: -36px;
 border-width: 0 90px 70px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: transparent transparent blue;
}
```

```html
<div id='pentagon'></div>
```

---

**How do I invert it?**

It is very simple to do once we have the understanding of how the shape is created.

- Change the trapezoid such that the bottom is wider than the top. That is, make `border-bottom` as 100px and set its color as `#abefcd`.  Change `border-top` to 0px. The color of `border-top` doesn't matter because it is anyway 0px wide.
- Similarly for the triangular part, set the `border-top` as 70px and its color as `#abefcd`. Change the `border-bottom` to 0px. This will make the triangle point down.
- Adjust the `top` value such that the triangle (pseudo-element) is below the trapezoid (which is 100px tall).

Answer (score 4):

An alternative would be just to keep the same code but add rotate the pentagon using a `transform` like so.

```css
#pentagon {
  margin: 70px 0 5px 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 110px;
  border-width: 100px 36px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #abefcd transparent;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
#pentagon:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  top: -170px;
  left: -36px;
  border-width: 0 90px 70px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent #abefcd;
}
```

```html
<div id="pentagon"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just inverse your `div` content by adding few new styles as mentioned below. Rest `HTML/CSS` keep as it is of yours.

```css
#pentagon {
     margin:70px 0 5px 20px;
     position: relative;
     width: 110px;
     border-width: 100px 36px 0;
     border-style: solid;
     border-color: #abefcd transparent;
     -moz-transform: scale(1, -1);
     -webkit-transform: scale(1, -1);
     -o-transform: scale(1, -1);
     -ms-transform: scale(1, -1);
     transform: scale(1, -1);
    }
    #pentagon:before {
     content: "";
     position: absolute;
     height: 0;
     width: 0;
     top: -170px;
     left: -36px;
     border-width: 0 90px 70px;
     border-style: solid;
     border-color: transparent transparent #abefcd;
    }
```

```html
<div id="pentagon"></div>
```